# Jenkins - If a build fails deploy the artifacts of the last successful build

Tags: continuous-integration, deployment, continuous-delivery, jenkins

Is it possible with Jenkins to deploy the artifacts of the last successful build if the current one fails at any point? If so how?

I'm currently using rsync to deploy my files from the workspace as one of my build steps.

I'm aware that there is a plugin called `BuildResultTrigger` which I can guess I can use but I have no idea how to access archived artifacts and tell my current build which one was the last successful build.

Comment: Is there any reason why won't you simply deploy whenever the build is successful? If doing so, whenever build fails, you already have the last successful version deployed. No need to re-deploy the already deployed version.

Comment: Because as part of the build process a deployment to a staging server is made and then some WebDriver tests are run on that (behat/mink). If those tests fail then I want the last known successful build to be deployed back to the staging server. Deployment to production is done as a post-build step.

Comment: Don't push to staging if the build fails.  Staging should see that as the equivalent of the build not having happened.  (Same as what @juhist said.)

Comment: Ok, but if the unit tests pass, then I want to deploy to staging, and THEN run the webdriver tests, which require a deployment.

Comment: Do you store the id / name / whatever of the last successful build? If so, can  your test script update that stored value if all tests pass, and your deployment script deploy artifacts pointed to by that id / name / whatever? If the tests don't pass, the value is not updated, so the last successful build is picked.

Comment: see [Where does my tool question go?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that when deploying, you copy the already deployed (successfully built and tested) version to someplace on the deployment machine.

Then, when running the tests on Jenkins (assuming you use command-line to start the tests):

```
ssh deploymentmachine rm -rf /where/you/store/them
ssh deploymentmachine cp -R /where/you/deploy/them /where/you/store/them
rsync -rvz /where/jenkins/built/the/files deploymentmachine:/where/you/deploy/them
ssh deploymentmachine sh runtests.sh || \
 (ssh deploymentmachine rm -rf /where/you/deploy/them; \
  ssh deploymentmachine cp -R /where/you/store/them /where/you/deploy/them; \
  ssh deploymentmachine rm -rf /where/you/store/them
  exit 1)
ssh deploymentmachine rm -rf /where/you/store/them
```

This should give you a false exit status on failure and re-deploy the last successful version.

Adapt the solution as needed (for example, you probably start the tests in another way than "sh runtests.sh", the deployment may require re-starting servers instead of just copying around files, and the directory paths need adjusting).